# How can I add a java application to a wix website

Tags: java, web, velo

I have recently coded (in Java) a limit calculator and I am trying to find a way to connect it to my wix website. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We'd love to help you, but we don't really know too much about your problem, or what you've tried so far. You are far more likely to receive an answer if you can show us things you've tried/resources you've seen. I would suggest you start by looking up how to use Java on the web, or seeing if there's anything on this at the Wix website.

Comment: The only way to run Java code in relation to a web site (these days) is on the server side (Servlet / JSP etc.).

Comment: Either you can do as Andrew says and Do the calculation on some Java server and send back the result in the response, or You can write the code with Wix Code in Javascript.